# Помогите с Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle

После переустановки Android Studio, при создании нового проекта выбивает ошибку:

```
Settings file 'C:\Users\Alexnoid\AndroidStudioProjects\IP_Try\settings.gradle' line: 9

A problem occurred evaluating settings 'IP_Try'.
> Could not get unknown property 'repositoriesMode' for object of type org.gradle.plugin.management.internal.DefaultPluginManagementSpec.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating settings 'IP_Try'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:111)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.applySettingsScript(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.process(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsEvaluatedCallbackFiringSettingsProcessor.process(SettingsEvaluatedCallbackFiringSettingsProcessor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.initialization.RootBuildCacheControllerSettingsProcessor.process(RootBuildCacheControllerSettingsProcessor.java:46)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor$2.call(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:49)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor$2.call(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.process(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:46)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoader.findSettingsAndLoadIfAppropriate(DefaultSettingsLoader.java:140)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(DefaultSettingsLoader.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsAttachingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(SettingsAttachingSettingsLoader.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.composite.CommandLineIncludedBuildSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CommandLineIncludedBuildSettingsLoader.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.composite.ChildBuildRegisteringSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(ChildBuildRegisteringSettingsLoader.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.composite.CompositeBuildSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CompositeBuildSettingsLoader.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.InitScriptHandlingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(InitScriptHandlingSettingsLoader.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.CacheConfigurationsHandlingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CacheConfigurationsHandlingSettingsLoader.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.GradlePropertiesHandlingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(GradlePropertiesHandlingSettingsLoader.java:38)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(DefaultSettingsPreparer.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer$LoadBuild.doLoadBuild(BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer.java:71)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer$LoadBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$prepareSettings$1(VintageBuildModelController.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$13(StateTransitionController.java:247)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:258)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transitionIfNotPreviously$11(StateTransitionController.java:221)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transitionIfNotPreviously(StateTransitionController.java:217)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareSettings(VintageBuildModelController.java:80)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.getLoadedSettings(VintageBuildModelController.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$notInState$4(StateTransitionController.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.notInState(StateTransitionController.java:150)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.loadSettings(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:101)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.AbstractBuildState.ensureProjectsLoaded(AbstractBuildState.java:109)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.GradleBuildBuilder.create(GradleBuildBuilder.java:58)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.GradleBuildBuilder.create(GradleBuildBuilder.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildScopedBuilder.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:206)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingBuilder$1.call(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:337)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingBuilder.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:334)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildToolingModelController$AbstractToolingScope.getModel(DefaultBuildToolingModelController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:106)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:113)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:76)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getBuildModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getBuildModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:120)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:131)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.beforeTasks(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.beforeTasks(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$fromBuildModel$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:177)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:258)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:177)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:177)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:73)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:140)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'repositoriesMode' for object of type org.gradle.plugin.management.internal.DefaultPluginManagementSpec.
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:88)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.getProperty(ConfigureDelegate.java:124)
    at settings_6xcfsfb3lmgac5yq52knk7t69$_run_closure1.doCall(C:\Users\Alexnoid\AndroidStudioProjects\IP_Try\settings.gradle:9)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:73)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:155)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:167)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.pluginManagement(DefaultSettings.java:325)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings_Decorated.pluginManagement(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:489)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:196)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:36)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BasicScript.java:138)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultDynamicLookupRoutine.invokeMethod(DefaultDynamicLookupRoutine.java:58)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.invokeMethod(BasicScript.java:87)
    at settings_6xcfsfb3lmgac5yq52knk7t69.run(C:\Users\Alexnoid\AndroidStudioProjects\IP_Try\settings.gradle:1)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
    ... 169 more
```

В гугле при запросе выдало что нужно изменить параметр org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2019m в Gradle.Properties на org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8. После этих изменений выдает:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.0.0
         project : > com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:8.0.0
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:84)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$400(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
```

Файл Settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencyResolutionManagement {
}
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "IP_Try"
include ':app'
```

Update:
Решил проблему установкой в настройках правильной версии SDK(Также на всякий случай поменял версии плагина Gradle и самого Gradle). Спасибо всем кто пытался помочь мне решить проблему

Comment: Сам файл `C:\Users\Alexnoid\AndroidStudioProjects\IP_Try\settings.gradle` то покажите.

Comment: Добавил в пост.

Answer (score 1):

У вас не там стоит закрывающаяся фигурная скобка. Должно быть так:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: Исправил, все так же вторая ошибка.

Comment: Одна проблема — один вопрос. Заведите [новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) по второй ошибке.

Comment: Первую ошибку я исправил, привел ее в посте для информации о том какие параметры я менял. Проблема именно во второй ошибке.

Comment: А ответ именно по первой ошибке.

Answer (score -1):

Решил проблему установкой в настройках правильной версии SDK. Также на всякий случай поменял версии плагина Gradle и самого Gradle.

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос. Ошибка из вопроса не может быть исправлена таким способом.